# JQuery Append To Multiple Elements Fails

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml

I'm trying to use jQuery's append() method to append common content to set of div's as follows:

```
$("#horizontal_menu").append(menu);
$("#vertical_menu").append(menu);
```

What I'm finding is that the content (in this case, menu) is getting appended to vertical_menu but not horizontal_menu.  Does appending to one <div> preclude you from appending that content to another <div>?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can flip it around using [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) like this:

```
menu.appendTo("#horizontal_menu, #vertical_menu");
```

If `menu` isn't a jQuery object just wrap it:

```
$(menu).appendTo("#horizontal_menu, #vertical_menu");
```

*Currently* what's happening is it does get appended, or more accurately *moved* to `#horizontal_menu`, then gets immediately moved again.  Passing a selector or multiple elements to [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) makes it clone and append to each internally.

Comment: Thanks.  This works, and it doesn't require me to assign a class to my <div>s specifically for use as a jQuery selector.

Comment: This isn't working....It only appends to the first one -: #horizontal menu. Has this changed in recent versions of jQuery?

Comment: @PratikBothra which version of jQuery are you on? A quick fiddle test shows it still working here: http://jsfiddle.net/81ea73aj/

Comment: @NickCraver - Any idea why the code is failing inside my jsfiddle?

Comment: @Pratik Bothra sorry if it is too late, chek this quick fix http://jsfiddle.net/LzaLhe3p/1/

Comment: @Christ Lol, I couldn't even remember why I had this problem :-)

Comment: this won't work when you're appending to multiple jQuery objects - they need to be passed as an array

Answer (score 11):

> Does appending to one  preclude you from appending that content to another ?

With respect to [jQuery wrapped] DOM elements, yes. Under the hood jQuery calls `appendChild`, which when called multiple times with the same element simply [moves it from its current position to the new position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/appendchild).

You can try [cloning](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to make a copy:

```
var $menu = $(menu);
$("#horizontal_menu").append($menu.clone());
$("#vertical_menu").append($menu.clone());
```

You can pass `true` to `clone()` if you want event handlers to be copied over as well.

Comment: Ah.  I didn't realize that append() was functionally a move rather than a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Another [cloning](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) twist:

```
        var menu = $("#menu").contents();
        menu.clone().appendTo("#ulOne");
        menu.clone().appendTo("#ulTwo");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue whereby I couldn't add the const removeLink via the normal .append() method. Using Nicks advice above I was able to get it working as such.

```
        const removeLink = $("<span class='removelink'/>").html("X").on('click', function() {
          $(this).prev().remove();
          $(this).remove();
          counter --;
        });

        $(removeLink).appendTo('.dogname-inputs, .dogage, .dogweight, .mealplan');
```